# Any way to configure Federated Search so it only fires when certain scope(s) are used in search?

Tags: search-scope, federated-search

What I'd like to do is set up search federation with Bing, only when the scope "External Search" is selected, but can't seem to figure out if this is possible.  Is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you are looking for [Bing Search Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21862).

> This connector returns results from the Bing search engine. See the
>   [Federated Search Connector Gallery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint//ff727944.aspx) for other connectors and
>   instructions for using connectors with specific Microsoft Enterprise
>   Search products.

If not then you might be looking for [this tutorial](http://manish-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/federated-search-in-sharepoint-2010.html) for setting federated search with search scope as bing.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

Since you said

> What I'd like to do is set up search federation with Bing

So I thought you might want to setup bing as federated search, anyway back to what you want, I don't think its possible as literally you want a search scope as "Bing" that users can use to search, but for creating a search scope you need a content source now you can give external websites as content source to your crawler to crawl & index so that users can search it later on, I hope you understand what I tried to tell you :).

Whoever down-voted me please give explanation and correct me where am wrong.

Comment: Not quite, I know how to set up Federated search, but wanted to configure when it's used based on the scope used.

Comment: @tekiegreg I updated my answer but in short its not possible to have bing as search scope within your site since your search crawler can't crawl bing's possible's results so you can't provide a content source for your search scope, I wonder why you don't want to use federated search anyway as it will keep your search results and bing results separate and if you just need bing's search result then I think there might be webpart out there you can use, Hope it helps :).